# caml query is not working to get checked out files by specific user only

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, caml-query, caml

Loop through all the folders in document library and fetch checked out files by specific user only

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the userID instead of the userName?

Comment: Danny is right you just need $user.Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser" LookupId="True" />
        <Value Type="Integer">USERID</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

Use the above where clause to find the checked out file by a specific user and replace "USERID" with that user's id.

Comment: Thanks a million Divya, Danny and Bunzab, It solved my problem.

Comment: You can use https://camljs.codeplex.com/ link for creating a CAML query. It shows how one can create CAML query using CamlJs-Console which is a Chrome extension.